# Pinta not opening

Tags: 16.04, pinta

I installed latest version of Pinta on Ubuntu 16.04, installation was successful but now I can't open Pinta at all. When I click on Pinta (on the menu tab), the button just starts blinking but does not open a program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output you get if you try to start it from terminal by `pinta` (please add it to question).

Comment: Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f'

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `pinta` and `glib-sharp` with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pinta libglib2.0-cil \
libcairo2 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk2.0-cil libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil \
libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil \
libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil \
libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil
```

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Can't find custom attr constructor image: /usr/lib/pinta/Pinta.Core.dll mtoken: 0x0a0003d8
Unhandled loader error: 8, (null) Mono.Addins, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756 (null)

Comment: Try to reinstall more packages.

Comment: I'm -not really familiar with Linux so.... which do you suggest?

Comment: See my updated answer above. Clean installation will consume more time.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help. I'll try to do that when kids fall asleep. :)